# Why does the word for kindness, 친절 (親切), include a character meaning 'cut off; to disconnect'?

Tags: etymology, character-meanings, sino-korean-words

친(親) - relatives, parents; intimate

절(切) - to cut; to slice; to disconnect

How does the second character relate to the meaning of 친절?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The character 切 has various meanings, not only 'to cut' or 'to disconnect'.
According to Naver dictionary, 切 has following meanings,

1. 끊다
2. 베다
3. ***정성스럽다*** <= 절 of 친절 used this meaning.
4. 적절하다
5. 중요하다(重要--)
6. 절박하다(切迫--)
7. 진맥하다
8. 문지방(門地枋)
9. 반절(反切: 한자의 음을 나타낼 때 다른 두 한자의 음을 반씩 따서 합치는 방법)
10. 간절히(懇切-)

    a. 온통 (체)

    b. 모두 (체)

When this character is used to express the meaning of a. and b., then its pronunciation is '체', not '절'. '일체' is a good example of this case.

Comment: I was aware that characters could have more than one meaning, but not that one character could have *that* many meanings. Is there one primary meaning, with the others related to it?

Comment: @topomorto If you are willing to think so, many of the meanings are somewhat related to an earnest/sincere feeling in the heart. 절박 切迫 is paired with 迫 which means urgent, so it means you are under a sense of urgency; 懇 itself means sincere, so 간절 means sincere. You should be able to relate 친절 too.

Comment: @topomorto If one goes back to the Chinese, the formation of the character tells you that "cut" (끊다) is the original meaning (七 is the phonetic component while 刀 means knife). Also the traditional Korean eumhun "끊을 절" gives you the principal meaning in the first bit of the phrase.

Answer (score 4):

切 is to cut as a verb. 切 is "desperate, sincere" as a adjective. Many of Chinese characters have several "parts of a speech" in their meaning. Usually each "part of speech" has nothing to do with the others. Those usages are historical. Nobody knows why.

Answer (score 1):

The primary meaning of「切」means *to cut*.

The extended meaning of this is *close, near*, analogous to English *cutting it very close* or *drawing a fine line*, from which the meanings *urgent* and *relative*「親切」arise.

You don't need to memorise 10+ definitions for「切」 - the usage is mostly *cut*, *close/near* or *pressing/urgent*.